# Evaluating quality of sources using factor analysis

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

Assume I have entities $e_i$ (let's say, persons) and am trying to approximate their numerical attribute $q_i$ (let's say, their age). For this, I'm using imperfect data from $3$ sources $S_1, S_2, S_3$. Source $S_i$ is defined on a domain $D_i\subseteq \{e_1,\ldots, e_N\}$ and gives me an approximation of the real value for any $e\in D_i$. Assume that $D_i\cap D_j$ is nonempty for each $i,j$.

Without having much other information, how can I evaluate the *quality of my sources*?

One idea I have in mind is to construct a "correlation matrix" $C$ having

- $1$ on the diagonal, and
- a Pearson correlation of sources $S_i$ and $S_j$ on the intersection $D_i\cap D_j$ where both sources are defined, on positions $(i,j)$ and $(j, i)$.

Then the C-eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue should correspond -- I guess -- to something like an "approximation of the true value", assuming that factors in the factor analysis are interpretable.

If this first factor is, let's say, $0.8\times S_1 + 0.3\times S_2 + 0.6\times S_3$, can I interpret it so that source $S_1$ is "better" and source $S_2$ is the worst?

Any feedback or references to this idea? -- does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you should probably use principal components analysis

A similar approach is used in intelligence testing - general intelligence (g) is defined as the first unrotated principal component from a PCA of a bunch of intelligence tests. The higher the loading, the more the test is assumed to represent general intelligence, and this is called its 'g-loading'.

There's information on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_factor_(psychometrics)

You can find more papers with your favorite search engine. Here's one: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0160289686900097

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, regarding PCA -- note that I don't really have the full data from all the sources -- my correlations are computed each one on a different set (intersection of the domains $D_i$ and $D_j$), I'm not sure what else I can do then get this pseudo-correlation matrix...

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you just have a correlation matrix, you can do PCA or EFA, can't you?

Comment: It's not a correlation matrix in the usual sense that I have full data, $N$ rows and $k$ columns ($k$ would be 3 in my example, with 3 sources). I only have limited data from each source. So, the correlation between source 1 and source 2 is computed on a subset {John, Peter, Pavel} and the correlation between source 1 and source 3 is computed on a different subset {Maria, Eva, Paul}. I'm putting all these correlations into one matrix and am calling it "correlation matrix". However, I'm not sure how to mimic PCA with such incomplete data...

Comment: Maybe I'm just not educated enough, but don't you need the actual full data to do PCA? If I only have a symmetric matrix (let's call it correlation matrix), can I do anything else than compute eigenvectors?

Comment: In R, the main PCA functions take either a data frame or a correlation matrix. http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/118-principal-component-analysis-in-r-prcomp-vs-princomp/

Comment: Ok -- I will study that, thank you!